# react- native latitude and longitude error

Tags: react-native, expo, location

I want to put the values of the longitude and latitude of the initial Region, the longitude and latitude obtained above, but I keep getting errors. What should I do?  I don't know how.

"latitude:37,
longitude: 127,"
This part keeps getting errors.

I made

const[la,setLa]=useState("Loading...")
setLa(latitude)
...

initialRegion={{
latitude:Number(la),

then error says latitude:<<'Nan'>>..

I think latitude is string.

How can I change string to number?

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions} from "react-native";
 
import { backgroundColor } from "react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ReactNativeStyleAttributes";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker }from "react-native-maps";

const { width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("Loading...");
  const [la,setLa]=useState("Loading...");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [ok, setOk] = useState(true);
  const ask = async () => {
    const { granted } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (!granted) {
      setOk(false);
    }
    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
    } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ accuracy: 5 });
 
    const location = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(
      { latitude, longitude },
      { useGoogleMaps: false }
    );

    
    setCity(location[0].district)
    
    
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    ask();
  }, []);

    return (
    <>
  
    <View style={{flex:0.16,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:40,marginTop:55,marginLeft:30}}>{city}</Text>
    </View>
    
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude:37,
            longitude: 127,
            latitudeDelta: 0.00922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.00321,
          }}>

      </MapView>

      
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="black" />
    </>
      

  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Show MapView when location is not null like this.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  
    yourlatitudelongitudestate && <MapView
    style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 40 }}
    initialRegion={{
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude ,
    latitudeDelta: 0.00922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.00321,
}}
/>
</View>
```

Comment: It doesn't work....

Comment: @yeinp try to replace location with your latitude and longitude state, check the edited answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand 'yourlatitudelongitudestate'.

Comment: @yeinp means the react state where  latitude longitude values are kept